# I am getting null value in the server side from CheckBox in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, checkbox

When I check the box, it shows it has a false value in the server side model but in the ajax call getting values it shows null values.

In the model class:

```
[Display(Name = "Is Buyer")]
public bool IsBuyer { get; set; }
```

In the Razor Page:

```
<div class="row g-my-4">
    <div class="col-md-10 g-pl-0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-md-7 g-pl-0 g-pr-0" id="IsBuyer">
                <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.IsBuyer)
                @*@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsBuyer, new { id = "CheckBuyer" })*@

                @*@Html.CheckBox("IsBuyer")*@
                Buyer
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use everything but nothing is working.

Getting data values to use ajax call

[image: Getting data values by js]

Here you can see the `IsBuyer` attribute is null = empty, and here on the server side it's getting false value however I have checked every check box but that's what I am getting back

[image: Server side result]

Comment: Try `$('IsBuyer').prop('checked')` instead of .val().

Comment: becomes undefined now, instead of empty

Comment: Sorry, should be `$('#TheCheckBoxId')`. Forgot the `#`

Comment: yah, i know like this `"IsBuyer": $('#IsBuyer').prop('checked'),` so it result is undefinded

Comment: but i guess it's about the id, where i should mention the checkbox id?

Comment: You have multiple problems, not just getting the checkbox value. All values in your `data` js object are empty or undefined. All the data in your userModel is null or default values in the controller. Where are you calling the jquery function? It should be called from the view.#

Comment: well all of them is null coz i am just testing one property which its IsBuyer!

Comment: Use the javascript console in your browser to verify the checkbox value first. Then once you've verified that when checked, the checkbox `checked` property is `true`, if the value is `false` in the controller you know the binding is not correct. Does your model bind to the controller correctly for all the other properties?

Comment: yah, the binding is correct, but the property is getting false in JS console, how can i change this when the user check the box>

Comment: Please create an [mre] showing the behaviour you're experiencing. Add a snippet with the checkbox HTLM from your form/page including any jquery/javascript so we can diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use usual `BeginForm()` block and post data like below:

```
@model Models.ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group row">
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(l => Model.IsBuyer) </p>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model.IsBuyer)
    </div>   

    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

In the controller code:

```cs
public IActionResult IndexTest()
{
    var model = new ViewModel() { IsBuyer = true };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult IndexTest(ViewModel data)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // your code here...
    }            
    return RedirectToAction("IndexTest", data);
}

// View data model class
public class ViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Is Buyer")]
    public bool IsBuyer { get; set; }
    // Additional propereties is defined here...
}
```